# Yii2 how to check if two models are already linked

Tags: yii2, relational-database, yii2-model

I have two models related through a junction table.

`$model->link()` is the method used to establish the relationship between the two models. It basically populates the junction table with the corresponding keys of both models.

If two models are linked and I try to link them again, there will be an error because the key pair already exists in the junction table. Then I'd need to check if this relation exists before attempting to link the models.

I think I could just create a model for the junction table and query for the proper record. The result of that query would tell if I need to perform the link.

The question is:

Is there a short and easy way to perform this check, using some yii built-in method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveQuery` has `exists()` method that does what you need. Let's assume you have a `Book` class that is linked to `Author` class. So `Book` has `getAuthor()` method. Here's how you find out if related record exists:

```
$book->getAuthor()->exists();
```

Note that `$book->author` returns an instance of `Author` (or an array if it's a `hasMany` relation), while `getAuthor()` returns an `ActiveQuery` instance.

Executing `exists()` still runs one SQL query just like `$book->author` would, but that query is more efficient than actually fetching the data and creating the corresponding model.

On the other hand, in many cases the performance improvement is negligible, so you can just run `isset($book->author)` and be done with it.

Comment: This will work for what I need. I would filter the results with `where()` `ActiveQuery` method to check for a particular record. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In general, it's preferable to have methods that return `ActiveQuery` or its descendants as opposed to returning arrays of models, because in the former case it's possible to add more conditions to your original query. You might want to do it with `andWhere()` in case the query has other conditions.

Comment: It works the same way - `$book->getAuthor()` will return an instance of `ActiveQuery`. From this query you can call `->all()` to get all entries, `->one()` to just get the first one or `->exists()` to get count and compare it to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I think that easiest way is just to call the relation method.
With model Foo and relation method for model Bar getBar() (defined with via junction table) (new Foo)->bar is null if there is no link. Of course this is valid in case of one-to-one relation. For one-to-many you have to check result array.

Comment: You're right, assuming you need exactly what is specified in relation. If a query needs to be further manipulated, it's a better idea to get the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've added this method to the model that needs to be linked
(in my case it is many-to-many relation):

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
 public function link($name, $model, $extraColumns = [])
 {
     $exists = $this->getJunctionModel()
         ->where(['other_model_id' => $model->primaryKey])
         ->exists();

     if (!$exists) {
         parent::link($name, $model, $extraColumns);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`$model->isRelationPopulated($relationString)`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#isRelationPopulated()-detail)