# Yii2, how to check relation by a query?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, relationship

I have two models, with relation via junction table. So, i am trying to get from db some models, that have not this relation. 
I can do this by [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574197/yii2-how-to-check-if-two-models-are-already-linked).
But how to do this by query ? Use with or joinWith methods, and check `IS NULL` at junction table columns ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create junction's model and add to your AR model method for it:

```
/**
 * @return ActiveQuery
 */
public function getJunctions()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Junction::className(), ['someId' => 'id']);
}
```

Then you can use it with query:

```
$query = Model::find()
    ->joinWith([
        'junctions' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
            $query->andWhere(['{{junction}}.id' => null]);
        }
    ], false);
```

Comment: In my case, i am not create a relation to junction table, but has one, that using it. So, i have a query like yours, data was empty (i  think the reason is in relation method). I change andWhere -> where and using default left join. And in this way, query is works. Thanks!

Comment: where clear all previous conditions (f.e from behaviors).

Comment: As you mentioned must use LEFT JOIN for this. My fault.

Comment: You right about `where`, but in which case i am not need first level conditions. In another case, `andWhere` is rather `where`.